How can we remove all undefined properties from an object, in TS?
I am trying to remove undefined properties from an object in TS. Below is my attempt. What am I missing here?
function objectWithoutUndefined<O extends Record<string, unknown>>(
  obj: O,
): { [K in keyof O]: O[K] extends undefined ? never : O[K] }  {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => obj[key] === undefined && delete obj[key]);
  return obj;
}

I am getting this error on the return line:

Type 'O' is not assignable to type '{ [K in keyof O]: O[K] extends
undefined ? never : O[K]; }'.
Type 'Record<string, unknown>' is not assignable to type '{ [K in keyof O]: O[K] extends undefined ? never : O[K]; }'. [2322]


TS will never be smart enough to see that the loop you're running over the entries will have some systematic effect on the type of the object. So you'll need to use a type assertion or the equivalent. But why are you claiming or expecting the type of a deleted property to be never? That's not what never means. At best you'd want to make the property optional with a value of never type, but this mostly just brings back the possibility of undefined. Distinguishing missing from undefined is a sketchy subject in TS. And you're mutating the input? That invalidates it.

(see prev comment). You could jump through all the hoops, including --exactOptionalPropertyTypes and come up with something like this. Is that what you want? If so I could write an answer, but... what's the use case here? Please [edit] to clarify what's in scope and out of scope here (especially things like mutating the input which invalidates its type, and whether or not undefined is allowed in the type of optional properties in general).

Thank you, @jcalz. I am trying to do something as basic as removing properties with undefined values. I am working with ZodError.flatten, which happens to return an index signature type that includes undefined explicitly as a property value. I want to remove those values as they are creating problems for me downstream (I am forced to place multiple type guards around the code, polluting it).

Sorry, could you address the specific questions I asked above? I know that at runtime you’re removing undefined properties, but I’m trying to understand what you’re doing with the types. Please re-read the comments and answer the questions (unless you want me to repeat or rephrase them here, let me know).

When I have an object type with potentially undefined property values, it is necessary to check whenever indexing the object with a set of known keys, whether the returned property value is undefined. In my specific case, that is an unnecessary annoyance, as I happen to know that when a ZodError is returned then it does have a value. It is hard to simplify it further without adding significant complexity to the OP.

I guess you didn't understand or want to reply to my specific questions. What happens if a property is of type string | undefined? What about optional properties? I provided a playground link to an approach which deals with those as best as I can, but note that optional properties will appear as having undefined in their domain and... ugh I'm just repeating myself. I'm not asking for simplification but clarification. You already accepted the other answer even though these questions remain, so I guess it's just academic curiosity on my part now.

@jcalz Apologies, I did not understand what you meant. I will think some more on this and explore your playground link again. Thank you for the help.

Instead of filtering the values, filter rather the keys:
Playground
function objectWithoutUndefined<O extends Record<string, unknown>>(
  obj: O,
): { [K in keyof O as undefined extends O[K] ? never : K]: O[K] }  {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => obj[key] === undefined && delete obj[key]);
  return obj;
}

const o = objectWithoutUndefined({p: undefined, p2: 'ok', a: Math.random()<0.01?0:undefined});
/*
const o: {
    p2: string;
}
*/


I think this is great, but this: Record<string, unknown | undefined> just resolves to Record<string, unknown>, so there is no need to add it except for documentation.

@JanekEilts indeed, fixed

And what happens when the property is optional or includes undefined in its domain? Like {a: Math.random()<0.01?0:undefined}?

@jcalz fixed, i guess this is the best we can do?

It really depends on the OP’s use cases. Maybe the property value should be filtered also? Maybe the property should be made optional? I asked questions but haven’t gotten answers so ‍♂️

Thank you. How do you come up with a solution like this? I am not sure where I would have started in order to get the idea that I should try putting the filter on the key-side instead of the value-side..

@Magnus just saw some solution where keys where filtered and immediately understood that's a perfect way to filter keys in many cases

The provided function has some type definition issues in its return type. Specifically, { [K in keyof O]: O[K] extends undefined ? never : O[K] } would produce a type incompatible with the actual returned object.
Here’s the implementation
function objectWithoutUndefined<O extends Record<string, unknown>>(
  obj: O,
): Partial<O> {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    if (obj[key] === undefined) {
      delete obj[key];
    }
  });
  return obj;
}


That would defeat the purpose. The returned type would not be the object without undefined properties.
